# How do I write a sql query to fetch the cost a and cost b of a product based on the selected state?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table in which I have headers in the following manner:

[image: mysql table called productpricing]

I am trying to write a sql query to lookup the product cost A and B based on the selected product name and state. I have not worked with something like this before; where I had to match the input textbox value with the header of a table to retrieve the desired outcome. Any help or guidance will be highly appreciate it.

Comment: Normalize your structure

Comment: ^^^^ yep. Anything else is just pointless

Comment: @Akina how do I normalize it? please guide, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**Hi jack,**

Did you try something like this?

```
SELECT[column_name| * |expression]<comparison operator>
[column_name | * | expression ]
FROM <table_name>
WHERE <expression>[comparison operator]<expression>;
```

here you can read more
[example](https://swcarpentry.github.io/sql-novice-survey/03-filter/)